# identify Buffer overflow in C

Tags: c, compiler-errors, overflow, buffer-overflow

I am confused in this code is buffer over or not because i is not initialized.
What I understand is that if i change int len = 64 its cause overflow

Please help me understand this code

Comment: What command line arguments are you passing?

Comment: Inside foo, what is `o`?

Comment: Your array `string` cannot hold a string of length `len` but only `len-1`. You forgot the terminating 0 byte. The condition must be `strlen(argv[1] >= len)` and of course you should first check `if (argc > 1)` before you access `argv[1]`

Comment: You already get an overflow if you provide a string of length 24. No need to go up to 64.

Comment: So, buffer overflow happened in this case?

Comment: Yes, copying `len+1` bytes into `string` causes overflow and making `len>24` also causes overflow when you copy into `buf[24]`. You know your sizes, you can easily see when you store too much data.

Comment: and what if i change strcpy(string, argv[1]) to strcpy(string, argv[1], len)?

Comment: Please make sure you provide sample code that at least compiles - yours won't.

Answer (score 0):

Your function "foo" is error,you can't return "o".

Comment: Welcome to SO. This does not answer the question which is about overflow. but should be a comment. If you have not enough reputation to write comments, that is no reason to use an answer instead.